# Duplicate App Listing in Intent Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I seem to be doing something wrong with deep linking in my app. I have two activities: a post viewer which views posts on a site, and a profile viewer which views a users profile. Below is my code that I've set up following Google's guide to deep linking.

## Profile Activity Manifest Declaration

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.ProfileActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.activity.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="gab.ai"
            android:pathPattern="/..*"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

## Post Viewer Activity Manifest Declaration

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.PostViewerActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.activity.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="gab.ai"
            android:pathPattern="/..*/posts/..*"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've left out the intent handling code because it is redundant. The deep links work properly, except for a weird issue when opening URLs that direct to the post viewer activity.

[image: root url]

This works perfectly. Tapping a link such as https://url/.. opens the dialog and lists only one option When selecting the app, it opens the proper activity perfectly.

[image: post url]

Here's where it gets weird. When clicking a URL such as https://url/../posts/.. the Android System sees both activity deep links as feasible. **My question is how do I get around this?** Changing the URL scheme is out, and I'm not fluent enough about deep links to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In `ProfileActivity` `android:pathPattern="/..*"` equals to `/..*/posts/..*` because an asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the immediately preceding character. Try to use escape character `\` as explained in [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Comment: So I guess my question now is...maybe I'm using the ..(asterisk since I don't want to italicize) wrong. The reason I am using that is because the two portions of the URL are dynamic. Am I using this wrong?

Comment: Also, following your advise, now none of the links open in the app. They only open in Chrome.